# android notification not shown on some android devices

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have to display a notification in my application when i receive a GCM message.
so i have written a code for notificaiton in android. the problem is

**1. on some devices the notification is not shown**
 **2. on some devices even if the notification is shown when i click on the notification the required fragment of a FragmentActivity is not show.**

These problems occur in **some devices** only

HERE is my code:

```
Context context = ctx;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(
            R.drawable.launcher_icon, "Notification message",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.friends.with.benefits.bang.facebook.dating.matchFbId", userID);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(context, 0, intent,0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "FriendsWithBenefits",
            "Hurray! You have a match on FriendsWithBenefits. Click here to check it out!", pIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(i++, notification);
```

I dont know why it is happening only on some devices?